# Извлечь фрагмент из строки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть такие строки такого формата;

1#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.4#0#

2#2017-10-26 09:28:16#540#0#

3#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.5#0#

4#2017-10-26 09:28:16#530#0#

5#2017-10-26 09:28:16#530.5#0#

как выбрать цифры только между предпоследних решеток "#538.4#", "#540#", "#538.5#", с учетом того что количество цифр может меняться.

Answer (score 2):

> Используйте регулярные выражения:

```
$array = [
    '1#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.4#0#',
    '2#2017-10-26 09:28:16#540#0#',
    '3#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.5#0#',
    '4#2017-10-26 09:28:16#530#0#',
    '5#2017-10-26 09:28:16#530.5#0#'
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $str) {
    preg_match('~#([\d.]+)#(?=\d)~', $str, $arr);
    $result[] = $arr[1];
}

print_r($result);
```

> Результат

```
 Array (
    [0] => 538.4 
    [1] => 540 
    [2] => 538.5 
    [3] => 530 
    [4] => 530.5 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Цифры нужно извлекать вместе с решётками или без? Если без, то:

```
$str = '1#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.4#0#';
$arr = explode('#', $str);
$num = $arr[2];
```

Для массива строк:

```
$strings = array(

    '1#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.4#0#',

    '2#2017-10-26 09:28:16#540#0#',

    '3#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.5#0#',
);

$nums = array();

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $split = explode('#', $str);
    $nums[] = $split[2];
}
```

Comment: Нет, это деление строки по разделителю, и все что получилась пишется в массив, а мне нужно что бы в массив писались только  такие числа 538.4, 540, 538.5

Comment: @Вова, что мешает создать новый массив, сделать цикл по всем строкам  и записывать выбранное число новым элементом массива? Впрочем, если непонятно, я добавил информацию в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать еще такой вариант:

```
$str = '1#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.4#0#
2#2017-10-26 09:28:16#540#0#
3#2017-10-26 09:28:16#538.5#0#
4#2017-10-26 09:28:16#530#0#
5#2017-10-26 09:28:16#530.5#0#';
preg_replace_callback('/#([0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)#/', function($s) {
    var_dump($s[1]);
}, $str);
```